# Конвертировать Json в Xml

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется ссылка, отображающая json код, после ее получения, мне необходимо конвертировать в XML формат.

Результат приходит сюда

```
var result = "https://launcher.nolosha.fr/api/news/launcher";
```

Далее, я пытаюсь конвертировать результат в xml

```
XmlDocument jsonToXmlNews = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(result, "NewsItems");
var serverNews = jsonToXmlNews.InnerXml;`
```

Код получаемого XML

```
<NewsItems><status>42</status><message>News showed</message><total>3</total><news><title>[INFORMATION] Bug des '3 FPS'</title><date>7/2/2017</date><link>https://forum.nolosha.fr/index.php?threads/information-bug-des-3-fps.4636/#post-28386</link></news><news><title>Compte-rendu de réunion staff - 01/03/2017</title><date>1/3/2017</date><link>https://forum.nolosha.fr/index.php?threads/compte-rendu-de-r%C3%A9union-staff-01-03-2017.5848/unread</link></news><news><title>BÊTA - 1.25</title><date>6/3/2017</date><link>https://forum.nolosha.fr/index.php?threads/bÊta-1-25-maj-14h-launcher.6117/</link></news></NewsItems>
```

Необходимо удалить из xml status, message, total, оставить только массив news

Comment: Выложите код и сам текст ошибки. Не понятно, что такое e.Result.Data. И лучше в описание вставьте json, а не ссылку.

Comment: e.Result.Data это текст, который выводится при загрузке ссылки. Исправила вопрос...  Мне нужно вытащить только объект news

Comment: Я имел ввиду убрать ссылку и вместо нее сам json файл прикрепить, чтобы не переходили по ссылке, и сразу видели файл, что Вам достать нужно)

Comment: Обновила вопрос

Comment: Подождите, тогда непонятен ваш вопрос. Вам нужно переконвертировать JSON в XML, или убрать из XML некоторые элементы? Это совсем разные проблемы.